# Syntax highlighting doesn't run after in-page edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, inline-editor

The syntax highlighting doesn't re-highlight the re-rendered post after an in-page edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in latest, also takes care of mathjax hooks.

Comment: You're fast!!  :O)