# Disabling syntax highlighting broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, syntax-highlighting

In [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13250762/923794) I wanted to prevent syntax highlighting as [described in here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

But it's not working. Not working means: Even though I said

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
```

before the start of the block, a couple of characters are still highlighted, probably because of the Python tag to the question.

Also thought [this (rerendering after in-page edit)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98231/syntax-highlighting-doesnt-run-after-in-page-edit?rq=1) might be an issue, so that only I see the wrong highlighting. But that's marked as fixed.

Is it my fault or a bug or none but expected behaviour? If the latter, why would we want this?

Comment: @Tim: Thanks! Any chance to include that in the documentation. The phrasing is not clear to me, and there's no example showing how these tags are included in surrounding text. Also, if you put your comment in an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Yeah, I had thought this had come up before so I was searching for a duplicate first, but was having a hard time finding something. Answered now. As far as the documentation goes, I can't personally update that, but I agree that expanding the example a little might help here.

Comment: Felt the same way, but after reading 20 questions about broken highlighting, I gave up. How are these documentation updates handled? Should I open up a feature-request question for that change?

Comment: Someone may act on this post if they feel it worthwhile, but posting something with [meta-tag:feature-request] [meta-tag:editing-help] should also be acceptable.

Comment: Appreciate the advice! Explicit is better than implicit - can't expect the busy folks to extract implications from some comments, so I've posted [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154796/170949)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have a newline before the language hint, just like you need a newline before a code block. I've gone ahead and fixed your post now.