# Please clarify syntax highlighting example in help to include empty line before markup

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting, editing-help

As a follow-up to a question about [why disabling syntax highlighting did not work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154786/170949) I'd like to propose to include or change at least one example in the [existing editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) to include the empty line before the markup.

So instead of showing

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    setTimeout(function () { alert("JavaScript"); }, 1000);
```

Illustrate

```
Surrounding text prologue

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    setTimeout(function () { alert("JavaScript"); }, 1000);

Surrounding text epilogue
```

Or at least clarify in text that a leading empty line must be included.

The location of where to place the language tag (empty lines before and after) and if it's itself indented or not, always confuses me, and I already checked the help on several occasions - only to be reminded again that the help does not clarify. Maybe there are more users like me ;-)